# Medical Imaging Application Automation via QTP

Tags: c#, .net, qtp, dicom

I have a medical post processing application which render's Dicom images into the my application. Application is developed using C#.net. My question is can we use QTP to automate the application. As new version of QTP UFT 11.5 possess new advanced features like(insight) where it really does n't bother about underlying technology. What would be the ad-dins requirement.

Thanks in Advance
Regards
Arun

Answer (score 1):

The [Insight feature](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855) can be very useful for testing an application that generates its own graphics however it does have its limitations. The answer to your question depends on the nature of the UI the application generates. At its base Insight uses image matching algorithms to find an image on the screen so if the application generates the same (or pretty similar) UI then Insight would be a good fit for you.

The best answer is to download UFT and play around with the application during he trial period to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. would be checking with the trial ver now. Any idea why everyone recommends Ver 11.52 over 11.5 UFT. Suggest's that add a patch over UFT Ver 11.5.

Comment: Because probably it is always recommended to use the latest version. HP fixes lots of bugs with each of their releases.